# How can I compile a PLSQL package

Tags: plsql, toad

How do I compile oracle package in sql prompt and using toad? I googled, I got answers only for recompiling, could not find anything for how to compile.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

```
ALTER PACKAGE <your_package_name> COMPILE PACKAGE;

ALTER PACKAGE <your_package_name> COMPILE BODY;
```

Comment: Is it for compilation or recompilation?

Comment: @user2659098 Compilation and re-compilation as well. Once a package is created it gets compiled even if there are any errors(compiled with errors). Subsequently there are re-compilations to package for correcting any errors or modifications.

Answer (score 2):

To compile both package spec and package body we can try below command:

```
ALTER PACKAGE <package_name> COMPILE

ALTER PACKAGE <package_name> COMPILE PACKAGE
```

To compile only package body, we can use:

```
ALTER PACKAGE <package_name> COMPILE BODY
```

In case we are using toad, we can select our package spec or body and then use <kbd>F9</kbd> key to compile either package spec or package body.

Answer (score 1):

In toad, if the package does not exist yet, you've got 2 options: F5 and F9, both from the SQL window where the package's code is. F9 is more convenient about compilation errors if any (in my opinion).

You'll have to be sure package specs are compiled before the body though. It can be done in 2 separated windows or only one, it does not matter.